# Why do I receive a copy of mail sent by sendmail?

Tags: php, gmail, sendmail

I have `sendmail` setup to route via `gmail`:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
auth_username=xxx@gmail.com
```

Sending with :

```
    mail(
     user@yahoo.com
    ,"subject text"
    ,"body text"
    ,'From: admin@domain.com'.PHP_EOL
        .'Reply-To: admin@domain.com'.PHP_EOL
        .'MIME-Version: 1.0'.PHP_EOL
        .'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'.PHP_EOL
    );
```

The user get the mail at user@yahoo.com as expected.
But I also receive a copy at xxx@gmail.com.

Why is that?

I had been using PHPMailer and did not have this problem, routing via gmail as well.

Comment: Certainly it is possible to configure such behavior in a sendmail setup, maybe also your SMTP server (gmail SMTP in this case) has such a setup. We can't really say much here except that this has nothing to do with php.

Comment: @arkascha I have not been able to find a detailed reference guide for sendmail, do you know of one?

Comment: The man page that comes with sendmail is pretty detailed...

Comment: I can;t seem to find that document, I have sendmail that came with xampp, no docs. I also downloaded from sendmail.org, but no manual I could find.

Comment: Oh, typically `sendmail` is installed on the system as a default package, uncluding the man page. I never understood why people use those `xampp` distributions since all packages contained can be installed and integrated cleanly into the system with a few mouse clicks anyway, so I am not really familiar with what is packed in that distribution. But a simple google search for "sendmail man page" reveals it as first hit... https://linux.die.net/man/8/sendmail.sendmail